# Converse of closed graph theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space. If for every Banach space $Y$ and for every linear operator $T:X\to Y$, graph of $T$ is closed implies $T$ is continuous, then can we prove that $X$ is a Banach space?

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: I do not know. It just came in my mind. However, I could not solve it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. The closed graph theorem in this form is equivalent to $X$ being a barreled space. See item 15 [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space#Characterizations_of_barreled_spaces)

There are incomplete normed spaces that are barreled. See [here.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03322742)